# Cover page : Tikz need explications

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, covers

I so on this forum a very nice way to create a cover page with the tikz package, I understand globally what the functions doing but I want to understand every instruction.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{page cs/.cd, x/.store in=\px, y/.store in=\py}

\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \tikzset{page cs/.cd, #1}
    \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}}
    {
        \pgfpoint{
            \px*\paperwidth
        }
        {
            \py*\paperheight
        }
    }
}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, font=\sffamily \bfseries \huge, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, white]
    \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{image.jpg}};
    \fill [cyan, opacity=0.5] (page cs:x=0,y=0.075) rectangle (page cs:x=1,y = 0.30);
    \node [scale=2.2, anchor=west] at (page cs:x=0.075, y=0.235) {Games of Thrones};
    \node [anchor=west] at (page cs:x=0.075, y=0.18) {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.};
    \node [anchor=west] at (page cs:x=0.075, y=0.12) {By George R. R. Martin};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The part that I don't understand are the tikzset definitions and the tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem. I try to look on internet but I didn't find any good explications of tikzset, what are .store, \px, \py ? What does pgfpointadd and pgfpoint ?

Best regards,
Zed13

Ps : sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are PGF syntax which is the basic layer behind TikZ. Roughly speaking, TikZ is the front-end, user-convenient parser for the actual graphics format PGF. There is also a system layer but you shouldn't need it unless you have serious intentions and a lot of free time.

Hence when you write for example a `calc` library notation

```
\node at ($(2,1) + (0,2)$) {A};
```

what is assumed is vector addition `(x1+x2,y1+y2)`. That is pretty much what `\pgfpointadd` does.

`\pgfpoint` is actually the low-level equivalent of coordinate syntax `(1cm,2pt)` such that you can write `\pgfpoint{1cm}{2pt}` It takes two arguments and expects to have two PGF registers to modify `\pgf@x,\pgf@y` (skipping a million details). But TikZ syntax has the advantage of a limited duck typing. In TikZ you can give a node name, an anchor of a node, an actual dimension, or just number etc. and it is processed and regularized to be used in `\pgfpoint` and so on. For example `(a.north)` is understood by TikZ but you need to change the corresponding macro name to
`\pgfpointanchor{a}{north}`. Thus, TikZ is really useful to have shortcuts.

---

The coordinate system declaration is useful if you require to refer to a certain object frequently or do computations relative to a fixed object.

Here the coordinates are taken and then added to the current page lower left corner such that it acts like you have a TikZ picture with origin is moved to the lower left corner. So when you write `(0.3,0.5)` it finds the lower left corner then computes the length `0.3 * page width` and `0.5 * page height` quantities and add to the lower left corner coordinates.

---

The `/.store` is a key-handler and there is no way it can be covered here in the answer. You need to read the `pgfkeys` section of the TikZ/PGF manual. Basically, instead of `\def`ining something you hold it in a key-based database or a `dict`-like structure in Python lingo.